# How to extract postgres timestamp range with Go?

Tags: postgresql, go, psql

I have a database calendar with tsrange type from postgres. It allows me to have multiple appointments and time range such as :

```
["2018-11-08 10:00:00","2018-11-08 10:45:00"]
```

How do I store this value in a Go variable ?

I tried

```
var tsrange []string
```

And when I log `tsrange[0]` it is empty. What is the proper type for it ?

More code :

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM appointments")
utils.CheckErr(err)

var id int
var userID int
var tsrange []string

rows.Next()
err = rows.Scan(&id, &userID, &tsrange)

fmt.Println(tsrange[0])
```

When I replace `var tsrange []string` with `var tsrange string` the log is `["2018-11-08 10:00:00","2018-11-08 10:45:00"]`.

Comment: Try `var tsrange []time.Time`. BTW which db driver you're using?

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Comment: Getting index out of range when logging `tsrange[0]` and an empty array when logging `tsrange` while setting `var tsrange []time.Time`. Driver used is the pq package (github.com/lib/pq).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the individual bounds of a range at the sql level.

```
// replace tsrange_col with the name of your tsrange column
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, user_id, lower(tsrange_col), upper(tsrange_col) FROM appointments")
utils.CheckErr(err)

var id int
var userID int
var tsrange [2]time.Time

rows.Next()
err = rows.Scan(&id, &userID, &tsrange[0], &tsrange[1])

fmt.Println(tsrange[0]) // from
fmt.Println(tsrange[1]) // to
```